# Entering a non-Muslim place of worship

Tags: halal-haram, other-religions

What are the rules in Islam regarding entering a non-Muslim place of worship? Is it always permitted? Always forbidden? Permitted in certain circumstances?  Does it matter whether the location is a place of worship for a monotheistic or polytheistic religion?

Comment: +1 Valid question, clear formulation and also what I am curious about!

Answer (score 2):

While there is nothing in the Qur'an forbidding it, it has been reported that the prophet refused to enter the Kaa'ba before ordering the pictures therein obliterated.

The Hanafi opinion is that since such places attract *shayateen* — especially if they contain prohibited images — entering them is *makruh tahrim*.  Without a compelling reason to enter, one should avoid doing so.

Comment: Where is the hanafi opinion sourced from?

Comment: @Ali OP didn't ask for a source, so i didn't bother digging one up.

Comment: So what if there are shayateen? When they hear of Islamic salat they will run away (if you believe in a particular hadith). It has no effect to a pious Muslim, especially when he is praying.

Comment: Should also go by "why"-- if on some religious intentions or while there's some ritual being held inside, I wouldn't feel comfortable being on either side. otherwise, I don't see anything wrong as long as done with respect on both sides.